# Azure Analysis Service - partition to refresh modified rows only?

Tags: azure-analysis-services

I have an AS tabular model that contains a fact table with 20 mil rows. I have partitioned this so only the new rows get added to each day... however occasionally, a historical row (from years ago) will be modified. I can identify this modified row in SQL (using the last modified timestamp) however would it be possible for me to refresh the row in SSAS to reflect this change without having to refresh my entire data model? How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, 20 million rows is not a lot. I’m expecting that will only take 5-10 minutes to process unless your SQL queries are very inefficient or very wide.  So why bother to optimize something which may be fast enough already?

If you do need to optimize it, you will first want to partition the large fact table by some date element. Since you only have 20 million rows I would suggest partitioning by year. Optimal compression will be achieved with around 8 million rows per partition. Over-partitioning (such as creating thousands of daily partitions) is counter-productive.

When a new row is added you could perform a ProcessAdd to insert just the new records to the partitions in question. However I would recommend just doing a ProcessFull on any year partitions which have any inserts, updates or deletes in SQL.

SSAS doesn’t support updating a specific row. Thus you have to follow the ProcessFull advice above.

There are several code examples including [this one](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-as-automated-partition-management/) which may help you.

Again this may be overkill if you only have 20 million rows.

Comment: Thank you. The business require the SSAS model be updated multiple times throughout the day to give a more “real-time” view of the data which is why I need to make sure it’s efficient and only refreshes the rows it needs to. Thank you for the code example I will take a look!

Comment: I haven't been able to work this one out.. if I processfull on any partitions that have updates/inserts/deletes... would it not just add them to the existing data in the model... creating duplicates?

Comment: @Jess8766 no. ProcessFull on a partition replaces all the old rows in that partition. Please do make sure you partition by a column that won’t change. If it does change a row could move from one partition to the other and you could end up with duplicates if you don’t ProcessFull both partitions.